# Why Laravel simple paginate doesn't working?

Tags: php, laravel

This this my controller

```
  class PageController extends Controller
  {

   public function showImageUrl (Request $req){

   $directory = '/public/testukas/';

   $files = collect(Storage::files($directory))->simplePaginate(8);

   return view('welcome')->with('files',$files);

  }
```

and this code from my appServiceprovider

```
  if (!Collection::hasMacro('simplePaginate')) {

        Collection::macro('simplePaginate',
            function ($perPage = 15, $page = null, $options = []) {
            $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
            return (
                new Paginator(
                    $this->forPage($page, $perPage),        
                    $perPage,       
                    $page,
                    $options
                )
            )->withPath('');
        });
    }
```

In blade template i use this to call links

```
 {!! $files->render() !!}
```

So my question is how to make it work, links doesn't show. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you need to put

```
{{ $files->links() }}
```

into your blade file.

> The links method will render the links to the rest of the pages in the
>   result set. Each of these links will already contain the proper page
>   query string variable. Remember, the HTML generated by the links
>   method is compatible with the Bootstrap CSS framework.
>   source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

*The Illuminate\View\View::render() returns the string contents of the view.*

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
{
    $allposts = Post::latest()->paginate(2);
    return view('welcome',compact('allposts'));
}


// blade file
{{ $allposts->links() }}
```